# What am I supposed to do in the warehouse with the train?

Tags: estranged-act-1

I came to a dark warehouse with a train in middle of it. I hear growling and I found a malfunctioning switch upstairs in, what looks like, a control room. I've spent a long time looking for ways to progress, but I haven't found any. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to figure it out on your own. It isn't that hard after all.

You're looking for a part to fix the malfunctioning switch in order to turn the powers back on, and to open the door. You can find many of these parts in the room next to the control room on the table next to the wooden boxes. Pickup the switch and take it to the control room. Insert it into the malfunctioning slot, turn the powers on and be on your way.